# Why does matching NULL require special syntax in SQL, and how do I get around it?

Tags: sql

I have a SQLite3 table with the following fields:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
street_name TEXT NOT NULL,
house_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
entrance TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
postal_code INTEGER NOT NULL,
city TEXT NOT NULL
```

So as you can see, the **entrance** can be `NULL`, and is even set to that by default. This is a problem when I'm trying to check if a specific address exists like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM street_addresses
WHERE
    street_name=? AND
    house_number=? AND
    entrance=? AND
    postal_code=? AND
    city=?
```

If I pass `NULL` to the **entrance** field, the query yields no results no matter what, because `entrance=NULL` is invalid. Instead I must use `entrance IS NULL`, but I can't edit the query to say `entrance IS ?` since that won't work when I pass anything other than `NULL`.

Is there any way to work around this *other than* building the query conditionally based on the value of `entrance`?

Comment: That has nothing to do with SQLite. This is how the SQL language works. You could use something like `coalesce(entrance,'') = ?` (don't know if SQLite supports that though).

Comment: To answer the question in the title of your question - `NULL` represents (to some extent) the concept that you do not *know* the current value (but you're assuming that the value exists). Take two cars, and assume that the amount of fuel in their fuel tanks is not known to you (both are `NULL`). Is the amount of fuel in one car equal to the amount of fuel in the other car? (Does `NULL` = `NULL`?). The answer is neither true nor false - it's unknown. Welcome to the world of three-valued logic.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: That's horrible... So there's no way to express "has no value" in SQL? Like if the car currently has no owner, what would you set the "owner" field? Certainly not `NULL`

Comment: That's where it gets a bit messy, and certainly back in the day, there were some proposed ways of dealing with this (that thankfully never made it into SQL) - at one point, some people were talking about having multiple `NULL`s - one that represents "no value", one that represents "unknown", etc. The SQL `NULL` tries to fit both of these uses, but there will always be edge cases where it falls down. In your example, I would use `NULL`, **unless** you need to distinguish between "no owner" and "owner unknown".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I now understand why fields that allows `NULL` don't work in unique indexes in MySQL. In MMORPG terms, you just granted me a ton of SQL experience. I might actually never use `NULL` again, since I never have, and probably never will, need an 'unknown' value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I can't edit the query to say `entrance IS ?` since that won't work when I pass anything other than `NULL`.

Yes, you can. This is not standard SQL, but a SQLite extension. From [SQLite Query Language](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL, then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not, then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is 1 (true). It is not possible for an IS or IS NOT expression to evaluate to NULL. Operators IS and IS NOT have the same precedence as =.

The same operation exists in standard SQL too, but using a different syntax: it would then look like `a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b`. This syntax is not yet widely supported, but most databases do have *some* way to express that. `a IS b` is the SQLite variation.

Answer (score 2):

(NULL is a thoroughly broken concept, but let's not go there just now…)

You can substitute a magic string to represent NULL — the empty string usually does the trick — and do this:

```
WHERE
    …
    COALESCE(entrance, '') = ? AND
    …
```

If you need to treat the empty string as different to NULL, the output of `uuidgen` will provide a magic string that is pretty much guaranteed not to match anything else (unless you're doing some self-reflective coding):

```
    COALESCE(entrance, '4F939D9A-F91E-4693-8DD5-F631FB11F061') = ? AND
```

Comment: The top Google response for "SQL NULL is a broken concept" is your comment on this page. Care to elaborate? :-)

Comment: @Codemonkey: Three-valued logic is well-known to be hugely problematic. You can start here, but the best treatment of the subject is by Chris Date: SQL and Relational Theory surveys the problems and offers SQL-specific guidance; Date on Database: Writings 2000-2006 analyses both 3- and 4-valued logic (Codd proposed 4VL to fix the problems with 3VL) in depth. Some examples: 1 = NULL and 1 <> NULL both fail, except in table constraints; NULL = NULL also fails, except in table constraints and when grouping.

Comment: …2VL has 16 possible truth-tables (all of which have intuitive interpretations) and all are constructible from a single operator (e.g., NAND) or a handy subset (AND/OR/NOT), while 3VL has 19,683 possible truth tables and no one knows of a useful minimal subset. Fundamental laws of logic are violated, the most egregious being the law of the excluded middle: p OR (NOT p) may not be TRUE, thus prohibiting trivial rewrites such as (A AND B) OR NOT A` ⇒ `(A OR NOT A) AND (B OR NOT A)` ⇒ `B OR NOT A`.

Comment: …In practical terms, for the above and other reasons, NULL is the source of countless bugs and considerable confusion among programmers. It also makes optimisers harder to implement, and therefore less effective. The problem now is that SQL was designed with NULL in mind, so while other ways of handling missing information exist, they frequently clash with the design of SQL engines. So, from a purely pragmatic standpoint, one cannot always avoid them. But one should always begin with a design that has no NULLs and fall back them only as necessary.

Comment: @Codemonkey: Earlier, I repasted my comments above to correct some errors, and just noticed that some URLs vanished in the process. "here" referred to [the Controversy section of the Wikipedia entry on NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Controversy). The two books, _SQL and Relational Theory_ and _Date on Database: Writings 2000-2006_ can be found on Amazon.

Comment: It might have been easier to put that extra information into an "Elaboration" section at the bottom of your answer. But in any case, thanks for the information and references :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special with how SQLite handles this, all (normal) relational databases uses this syntax.

You can change your code to this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM street_addresses
WHERE
    (street_name=?  OR (street_name is null  and ? is null)) AND
    (house_number=? OR (house_number is null and ? is null)) AND
    (entrance=?     OR (entrace is null      and ? is null)) AND
    (postal_code=?  OR (postal_code is null  and ? is null)) AND
    (city=?         OR (city is null         and ? is null))
```

Note that since you're not using named parameters, you have to specify all parameters twice.